# How to share a database between ASP.NET MVC 5 application and .NET console application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two projects in separate solutions - an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and a console application - using the same database. Both of them using **Entity Framework Code First migrations**. Each project uses a **duplicate of the models** (that is, each project uses the same models, I have just copied and pasted the class files into each solution).

What is a better way to handle changes to the models? For example, if I were to update the models in the web project, I would then need to copy and paste the files over to the console application and vice versa. Not to mention this, with each change I constantly have a headache of trying to update the database twice from each project. Any suggestions?

I have seen some suggestions about moving resuable code (i.e. the models) into a class library. However, my DB Context for the Web applications uses the Identity models whilst my console application does not. Will this be an issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need 3 projects: Console App, MVC, and a Class library that will be your model shared between the other two.

Comment: Should I move them all into the same solution? Should I have a different Db Context for each project (keeping in mind the Web project uses Identity models)?

Comment: you'll have only one DbContext that will be in your class library.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am running into an issue though - public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> - I must remove <ApplicationUser> in order for some LINQ queries to work and must add it in for Accounts to work. Not sure how to handle this?

Comment: You should decouple aspnet identity from mvc project.

Answer (score 0):

I have handled this by making a class library that contains all of the models that are common between the projects and publishing it to our private NuGet server, that way, if nuget is set up correctly, updates and changes will automatically be pulled from the nuget server when they are available.

Comment: Should I move them all into the same solution? Should I have a different Db Context for each project (keeping in mind the Web project uses Identity models)?

Comment: Keeping them in the same solution is not necessary, even if not using Nuget. Even if they were in the same solution but still different projects, it is entirely down to you to set up each project, so seperate DBContext is not an issue